# Splitting a user inputted string and then printing the string

Tags: java, error-handling

I am working through a piece of self study, Essentially I am to ask the User for a string input such as "John, Doe" IF the string doesnt have a comma, I am to display an error, and prompt the user until the string does indeed have a comma (Fixed.). Once this is achieved I need to parse the string from the comma, and any combination of comma that can occur (i.e. `John, doe` or `John , doe` or `John ,doe`) then using the Scanner class I need to grab John doe, and split them up to be separately printed later.

So far I know how to use the scanner class to grab certain amounts of string up to a whitespace, however what I want is to grab the "," but I haven't found a way to do this yet, I figured using the `.next(pattern)` of the scanner class would be what I need, as the way it was written should do exactly that. however im getting an exception InputMismatchException doing so.

Here is the code im working with:

```
while (!userInput.contains(",")) {
           System.out.print("Enter a string seperated by a comma: ");
           userInput = scnr.nextLine();
           if (!userInput.contains(",")) {
               System.out.println("Error, no comma present");
           }
           else {
               String string1;
               String string2;
               Scanner inSS = new Scanner(userInput);

               String commaHold;
               commaHold = inSS. //FIXME this is where the problem is
               string1 = inSS.next();
               string2 = inSS.next();
               System.out.println(string1 + " " + string2);
           }

       }
```

Comment: Note, the .split() is obviously wrong, I forgot to remove it before posting the code, I was just messing around with other bits of code to see if I could get it to work.

Comment: Use [Edit] and fix your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved simply by splitting and checking that the result is an array of two Strings

```
String input = scnr.nextLine();
String [] names = input.split (",");
while (names.length != 2) {
    System.out.println ("Enter with one comma");
    input = scnr.nextLine();
    names = input.split (",");
}

// now you can use names[0] and names[1]
```

**edit**

As you can see the code for inputting the data is duplicated and so could be refactored

Comment: Your solution has helped put this to rest, though I had to mess with the code a bit to get it to the standards of what the work wants, your solution did put me on the right path for that, and im greatful.